# Formation du passé composé

Tags: passé-composé, auxiliaires

I came about the following sentences:

> 1. Ils sont rentrés en ville
> 2. Ils ont retrouvé le travail

I just want to ask the following:

- Can we use "rentrés" in sentence (2), and "retrouvé" in sentence (1)? In other words, can they be exchangeable?
- For the first sentence, does using "sont" mean that the sentence is continuous? Like "they are returning to the city"?
- Can I use "sont" instead of "ont" in the second sentence?

Answer (score 3):

The tense you want to use in these two sentences is the *passé composé*.
It's a compound tense. It needs an auxiliary (*être* or *avoir*) and the past participle of the verb.

Please read those :

- A beginner's lesson on the *passé composé* [in French](http://www.bonjourdefrance.com/n7/cdm2.htm).
- A beginner's lesson on the *passé composé* in [English](http://www.languageguide.org/french/grammar/conjugations/passecompose.html).

You can see from the lessons that *rentrer* (derived from *entrer*) needs *être* as an auxiliary. And *retrouver* (a transitive verb) needs *avoir*.
The choice of *être* or *avoir* has nothing to do with what some English grammars call "continuous". This continuous aspect does not exist in French, forget about it when you study French.

Whether you use *être* or *avoir* does not change the tense of the sentence. 
Although I'm all against translating when learning a language, I'll dot it here to hammer home the point. Both sentences would translate either into the preterite in English or the present perfect according to context.

> Je les ai vus, ils sont rentrés en ville hier.

That would be a preterite in English.

> Leur fille est tombée malade et ils sont rentrés en ville.

That would be a present perfect in English.

---

*Rentrer* and *retrouver* have different meanings and of course you could not use one in place of the other if you want your sentences to keep their meanings.